# How to deliberately lose packets originating from an executable

Tags: c, networking, packet

I'm testing some code that is based on a hang in getaddrinfo. Supposedly getaddrinfo can hang if it never gets a response. So I'm trying to test this on my mac with a simple program that calls getaddrinfo. My hope is that I can intercept the packets originating from my executable (a.out) and drop them. Is there a way to do this or any other method to test this?

I don't think denying access to the exe would work since it would still be getting a response and erroring out so I'm really not sure of another way other than "losing" the packets so it never knows if it is failed or just waiting.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit heavy for the task, but if you have a VM set up in VMWare, you can set the network adapter to have a percent packet loss, and it will drop packets for you. Other virtualization software like GNS3 likely has similar options.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Which of us is more heavy-handed?

Comment: @Joshua Ha, I'm not sure. I've never manually edited `resolv.conf` before. If you're in a VM though, you could just revert to a snapshot, so it may not be "heavy-handed" in the sense of being irreversible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and point it to addresses that are firewalled. Then `getaddrinfo()` won't receive a response and you can see the hang. Spoiler: it times out after awhile. Some people who really don't want the long pause call it in a background thread.

Comment: Ok, so I can add something like `example.com 123.456.789.010` where `123.456.789.010` is blocked by my macs firewall?

Comment: @TreeWater: That's not how it works. The lines read `nameserver 123.456.789.010` so when you put that in you hang all DNS lookups. Tread carefully.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. So while this line is there I won't be able to resolve any hostnames then, correct? And then to undo it I just remove the line?

Comment: @TreeWater: To undo it you change the line back to what it was before.